# Cannot find module while adding cloud code to parse server example project

Tags: node.js, parse-cloud-code, npm-install, parse-server, npm-start

I have created a project from here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

I have followed instruction here http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-server-video-series-april-2016/

And installed the node.js and parse sever locally, I ran the parse server and it worked fine.

Next, I added my own cloud code to cloud directory, also replaced my main.js file. Now when I run the server (`npm start`) it I get this error

```
 C:\Project>npm start

> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start C:\Project
> node index.js

1
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cloud/afterSaveEvent.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\cloud\main.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this attIn with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Project\npm-debug.log

C:\Project>
```

Here is how my cloud code main.js file looks

```
require('/cloud/afterSaveEvent.js');
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(reqest, response) {
  response.success('Hi');
});
```

I have also tried reinstalling npm but got same error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Require `afterSaveEvent` like this : `require('./afterSaveEvent');`

Comment: Thanks Ebrahim, I have tried this before but I don't know why this time it worked. Now I am getting different error as below,
throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled
with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/sen
chalabs/connect#middleware.');

Comment: @JigneshPatel Please open a new issue for that.

Comment: I have posted question and found the answer by my self you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263205/parse-cloud-code-error-for-body-parser-on-npm-start-command/38264750#38264750

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need below line.

```
require('/cloud/afterSaveEvent.js');
```

Remove it and have only below code starting line # 1, it should fix the issue:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(reqest, response) {
  response.success('Hi');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding my question.