# Parse cloud code error for body-parser on npm start command

Tags: express, parse-cloud-code, parse-server, body-parser, npm-start

I have created the project for parse cloud code and now I am trying to start it using node.js

When I run `start npm` command it gives following error.

```
:\Project>npm start

> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start C:\Project
> node index.js

1
C:\Project\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:89
      throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundled
with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/sen
chalabs/connect#middleware.');
      ^

Error: Most middleware (like bodyParser) is no longer bundled with Express and m
ust be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#mi
ddleware.
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.get (C:\Project\node_modules\express\lib\
express.js:89:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\cloud\plivo_receiver.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Project\cloud\main.js:6:1)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs parse-server-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls parse-server-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Project\npm-debug.log
```

As per the instruction in error I checked  [https://github.com/sen
chalabs/connect#middleware](https://github.com/sen%20chalabs/connect#middleware) but could not understand the solution.

Error is being generated at following code of line.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved.

I have used it in other way as below.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var methodOverride = require('method-override')

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser);
app.use(methodOverride);
```

I found the article here [Body-parser Installation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#installation) for bodyParser and have done similarly for methodOverride.

May be it will help someone and save his/her time.

Thank you